# Tensorflow run 2 frozen graphs at the same time (parallel)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Is it possible to run multiple tensorflow object detection models at the same time? (I have trained two models and want to run both parallel)
I wrote this code and tried to run but it doesn't work.

```
# First Frozen
detection_graph1 = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph1.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH1, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# Second Frozen
detection_graph2 = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph2.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH2, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

def run_inference_for_multiple_images(path,graph1,graph2):
  with graph1.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess1:
      with graph2.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess2:
          #detection code..
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's absolutely possible, but you're doing it wrong.
Don't define the two models in two separate graphs, just load them in the same one (and add proper name scopes to avoid naming conflicts):

```
graph = tf.Graph() # just one graph, with both models loaded
with graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH1, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='first_graph')
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH2, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='second_graph')

# [...] get the correct input and output tensors for the two graphs via their names

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess: # just one session
  # Running only one of the two at a time
  res_1 = sess.run(outputs_from_graph_1, feed_dict=graph_1_feeds)
  res_2 = sess.run(outputs_from_graph_2, feed_dict=graph_2_feeds)

  # Actually running them in parallel (might not fit in memory!)
  res_1_and_2 = sess.run( outputs_from_graph_1 + outputs_from_graph_2, {**graph_1_feeds, **graph_2_feeds} )
```

**Note**: I'm assuming the feeds are `dict`s with `tensor_name:values` or `placeholder_tensor:values` key/value pairs